# Recursively draw rectangles in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently coding a Sierpinski Carpet. Now i have the problen, that it works per iteration only once and not at every square on my whole screen.
This is the code i use:

```
private void Carpet(Graphics g, SolidBrush brush, Single
    x, Single y, Single width, Single height, int iteration)
    {
        if (iteration == 0) {}
        
        else
        {
           
           
          
          for (int i = 0; i < iteration + 1; i++)
            {

                 width = Convert.ToSingle(Width / Math.Pow(3,i-1));
                 height = Convert.ToSingle(Height / Math.Pow(3, i-1));
                

                Single x1 = x + width/3;
                Single x2 = x1 + width;
                Single x3 = x2 + width;
                Single y1 = y + height/3;
                Single y2 = y1 + height;
                Single y3 = y2 + height;


                g.FillRectangle(brush, x1, y1, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x1, y2, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x1, y3, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x2, y1, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x2, y3, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x3, y1, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x3, y2, width / 3, height / 3);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x3, y3, width / 3, height / 3);
                
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i enhance my code, so it recursively draws Rectangles everywhere and not just on the first part of my Screen.
[image]

Comment: [Draw a Sierpinski carpet in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/01/draw-sierpinski-carpet-c/)

Answer (score 1):

You draw only the smallest rectangles and nothing else. But to find the position of all of them you have to have a recursive function. So, determine coordinates and call itself recursively in all iterations except the last one. If it's the last iteration then draw just one rectangle that fills the whole area given with `(x, y, width, height)`.

Instead of the `for` loop you have to have eight recursive calls. And in case of the last iteration you call only one `g.FillRectangle`. But now the problem is how to determine which iteration is the last one? When you call `Carpet` recursively call it with `iteration - 1`, and the last iteration is then the one with value zero.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I think it helped me to understand whats the problem.
And sorry for the long time that i havent answerd and thanked you. :)